# Different behavior when assigning a function to a variable or a table

Tags: lua, lua-table, first-class-functions, zerobrane

I have got a different behavior between a table and a simple variable assignation with a function. This difference does not exist when assigning a number for instance.

```
-- works fine
arrNum={1234}
Num=arrNum[1] -- Num=1234
arrNum[2]=arrNum[1] -- arrNum={1234,1234}

--does not work fine
arrFunc={function(x) return 10*x end}
func=arrFunc[1] -- func=function(x) return 10*x end
arrFunc[2]=arrFunc[1] -- arrFunc={function(x) return 10*x end,nil}
```

func is function(x) return 10*x end
but :
I get arrFunc={function(x) return 10*x end,**nil**} instead of arrFunc={function(x) return 10*x end,**function(x) return 10*x end**}

I don't understand this difference when for me func and arrFunc[2] are just the same "box" for receiving data, including first-class functions.

May be a clue (I do not catch) : in the console, after the last line is executed, I have the following info :

```
arrFunc

{function() --[[..skipped..]] end --[[function: 0x90d7d0]], nil --[[ref]]} --[[table: 0x93afc0]] --[[incomplete output with shared/self-references skipped]]
```

Comment: When I run `print(type(arrFunc[2]))`, I get `function`. Maybe whatever you're using for output wants to avoid creating a separate function, since the original is a reference to the first.

Comment: It seems that a table does not accept two references to the same thing. Thus arrNum[1]=arrFunc ; arrNum[2]=arrFunc create {arrFunc ; nil} . Since a function like a table is pointed through a reference, this could be the reason for the problem.

Comment: A table can definitely hold multiple references to the same thing. Like I said, the issue must be with your console.

Comment: I did not understand you were targeting the IDE I use, namely ZeroBrane, a nice editor by the way (console and on-site comment). But you may be right : despite arrFunc[2] is displayed by the IDE as nil, the type is said "function" and above all print(arrFunc[2](3)) is working and displays 30 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the problem has nothing to do with lua but seems to be an artefact of the IDE.

It seems the displays of my ZeroBrane console and on-site comments are erroneous. When I execute the program, everything runs just fine.

Comment: I'm guessing that when the console outputs a table, it wants to show a table constructor that can be copied back into a Lua program without changing its meaning. This isn't possible when the table has two references to the same thing, because a literal table constructor would end up making copies which may be changed independently. This would explain the `nil --[[ref]]` as an indication that it's unable to show the real value.

Comment: I contacted the ZeroBrane support for the debugger. For them, it is a "feature", although I personally did not understand why this was a feature...